# Multivariate technique to determine whether an effect is intermediate to two or more other effects?

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, discriminant-analysis

Let’s say I am looking at soil microbial community structure. I have a multivariate dataset with 20 dependent variables indicating various soil microbial biomarkers in the soil.  My treatments include different plants grown in the soil by themselves (e.g., species A, B, C) and in mixture (e.g., AB, BC, AC, ABC).

Now let’s say I conduct a MANOVA and determine there is a significant effect of treatment on the soil microbial biomarkers.

That's nice but what if I also want to know though whether the effect of the mixtures is intermediate to the effects of the constituent species? For example, what if I want to know whether the effect of AB is to be expected as based off the effects of A and B separately? To put it in another and more specific way, are there any emergent effects associated with mixing AB that are not predicted on the basis of A and B alone—that is, is the effect of mixing the species non-additive?

I have thought that from a rough, qualitative perspective, I could create plots of either the first two discriminant scores or the first two principal component scores for each treatment and visually assess whether the mixture treatments fall between the constituent single species treatments. For example:

[image: Example]

Beyond that though, I am at a loss. Is there an established way to quantitatively answer this kind of question?

(Also, I am not sure as to the implications of using principal component analysis versus discriminant analysis in this context. I see both in this kind of literature without much explanation at to why one and not the other. Any clarification on this point would also be appreciated.)

Comment: +1, nice sketch. Do you have a control condition with no plants growing? It seems that you could model this as three different treatments (factors): factor A, factor B, and factor C. Each of them can have two levels: present or absent. Then you will have a three-way MANOVA with three factors and all interactions between them, and can use MANOVA's test for whether the interaction effects are significant.

Comment: I do have a control condition. I also have species specific biomass data. So conceivably I could also go beyond present/absent and specify the actual amount of each plant. I hadn’t thought of this approach, but it seems analogous to what I would do if I was looking at only one dependent variable (versus twenty), which makes it a lot easier for me to wrap my head around. I will try it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @amoeba Angela didn't tag you here.