# Determine effect of two variables together vs seperate

Tags: statistical-significance

I have a data analysis problem. I am trying to identify the effect that a number of binary variables (v1, v2, v3... v25) have on a numeric outcome measurement, let's call it the 'W-value'.

I have collected a set of data points, each with a randomized choice of variables (though always 10 positive and 15 negative variables), and found the W-value for each data point, always between 0.0 and 1.0.

To determine the effect of each variable in isolation I used the Independant Samples T-test, where from the total set, for every variable, I extracted a randomized sample of data points where the variable was true and a sample where they were false, guaranteeing that they did not overlap in data points, and calculated the T-value based on the difference between the mean W-value of the two.

My problem is this: I want to figure out how to determine if two variables together can have an impact on the W-value, beyond what each variable contributes individually.

I had thought to simply add the W-value difference of the individual variables together and compare with a W-value difference of a new sample where both variables are positive, but A. I lack a way to determine significance that way and B. It feels like I am doing something wrong.

I did find this question, which seems like it is asking a similar question, but have not been answered: [Multivariate technique to determine whether an effect is intermediate to two or more other effects?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165260/multivariate-technique-to-determine-whether-an-effect-is-intermediate-to-two-or)

I took a quick look at MANOVA, but I am not sure that it is what I need in this case, though I might be wrong.

I apologize in advance if this question have been answered beforehand, and for the simplified explanation of the problem, I am not intricately familiar with the terminology of the field.